# Method returns a list of superclasses instead of subclasses

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, type-conversion, subclass

I have a `class X` which represents an element. Classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are subclasses of this and add additional behaviour to an element.

I have an `enum ElementType` with values `TypeA`, `TypeB`, `TypeC` and `TypeD`.

In my current scenario there is a `class Y` which holds a Collection of type `X` and has a `method GetElementsByType(ElementType type)`.

When this method is called I want to return a list of every item in the list with elements according to the type.

In my first attempt I ended up with this, but this resulted in conversion errors between the superclass and subclasses.

```
public List<X> GetElementsByType(ElementType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case ElementType.TypeA:
                return Elementen.OfType<A>().ToList();
            case ElementType.TypeB:
                return Elementen.OfType<B>().ToList();
            case ElementType.TypeC:
                return Elementen.OfType<C>().ToList();
            case ElementType.TypeD:
                return Elementen.OfType<D>().ToList();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

In my 2nd attempt I tried avoiding this conversion by making each subclass implement a common interface which should avoid conversion errors.

I ended up with this:

```
public interface IElement {
}

A : X, IElement
B : X, IElement
C : X, IElement
D : X, IElement


public List<IElement> GetElementsByType(ElementType type) {
            switch (type) {
                case ElementType.TypeA:
                    return new List<IElement>(Elementen.OfType<A>().ToList());
                case ElementType.TypeB:
                    return new List<IElement>(Elementen.OfType<B>().ToList());
                case ElementType.TypeC:
                    return new List<IElement>(Elementen.OfType<C>().ToList());
                case ElementType.TypeD:
                    return new List<IElement>(Elementen.OfType<D>().ToList());
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
```

However, when I call this method from somewhere, e.g.,

`var result = obj.GetElementsByType(ElementType.TypeA).FirstOfDefault(a => a.PropX == variable)`

I noticed the lambda expression couldn't retrieve any of the properties from the `Element` but am instead left with everything defined inside IElement (nothing).

How can I fix this so I can call a single method, add an enum as parameter and return a `List` of subclasses from a single `Collection` defined as the superclass?

Comment: Why do you need `ElementType` enumeration at all? Since the type of list items must be specified, wouldn't `List<A> myList = GetElementsByType<A>();` be sufficient? In other words, couldn't you make the type a generic type parameter instead of a function parameter?

Comment: The choice for a function parameter was made entirely because I didn't know about the type parameter yet. I've followed the directions from Kenneth and you and am resolving my issue using type parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this a bit simpler:

```
public List<T> GetElementsByType<T>() where T : X
{  
        return Elementen.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: I haven't touched this (`where T : X`) part of C# syntax yet, thanks for pointing me towards it. How would I go about calling this method with a parameter? I don't see where the type that should be queried is defined.

Comment: Oops, little typo, forgot to add the generic argument. I edited the answer

Comment: @Kenneth Now that's better :) Assuming that the OP is fine with this solution (i.e. generic type parameter instead of his `ElementType` parameter) this will do the trick.

Comment: Aha, that cleared it up! Thanks a lot, You've just made my code 95% smaller and 10 times easier to read.